# Best way to store an historic of info using MongoDB?

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I have a collection called users and inside it i have an attribute called "weight" which has a number attribute and a date attribute. The user can update its weight but i need to save an historic with all its previous weights and the day it was updated. I'm not really sure on how i should architect that.
How is the best day to do it? I'm using NestJS and Mongoose.

Comment: Since you've chosen to use a document database, why not store the user's weights as an array, and the most current is at the top.  Or just store the historical weights in an array while keeping the current weight as a separate property.

Answer (score 0):

The best model depends on what are the most common queries used by your application, so we probably need more context about your application to suggest the best model. That being said, I would suggest using a separate collection for the weights, having the userId, weight and date fields.

That makes sense when you sometimes make queries for the user data and don't need the weights historic at all and other times you want to query only for the weight historic specifically, maybe to display some data for the weight evolution, averages, and stuff like that.

If you use the user data together with the weight historic most of the time,  you can go with embedding an array of weight documents in the users, however, the queries could be a bit more complicated dealing with the array of nested subdocuments.

Comment: For now i just need to store the weight historic, don't think i'll need it for something else. Maybe a screen to display it in the future.